# Как заполнить таблицу по диапазону заданому в другой таблице

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle18c

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  start_range  varcahar2(10),
  end_range varcahar2(10),
  val_range NUMBER(10)
);
```

На начальном этапе заполнены два поля: `start_range = a1; end_range = a5;`

Можно ли как-то заполнить совсем другую таблицу `table2` со строками в диапазоне между `start_range` и `end_range`?

Чтобы получилось так: `(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)`.

Comment: Да обычный рекурсивный СТЕ. Довольно простой...

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, вот так:

```
create table t1 as 
    select 'a1' start_range, 'a5' end_range, 0 val_range from dual
/    
create table t2 (key varchar (10), val number (10))
/
insert into t2
select cast (ch||trim (column_value) as varchar (10)), ns+rownum-1 
from (    
    select 
        regexp_substr (start_range, '^\D+') ch, 
        to_number (regexp_substr (start_range, '\d+$')) ns, 
        to_number (regexp_substr (end_range, '\d+$')) ne
    from t1), xmlTable (ns||' to '||ne) 
/
```

В результате целевая таблица заполнится так:

```
select * from t2
/
KEY               VAL
---------- ----------
a1                  1
a2                  2
a3                  3
a4                  4
a5                  5
```